# Issues install ng-boilerplate and grunt

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

Hi I am trying to install ng-boilerplate successfully but I can't seem to be able to do it.
I have the following things already installed.

- npm 1.4.14
- node 0.10.29
- bower 1.3.5
- brew 0.9.5

but when I try to install grunt using the following command:

```
$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

It displays an error.I have typed out the error below. Can anyone please help me to install is properly.

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires lru-cache@'~2.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/lru-cache,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/bower-registry-client requires request@'~2.27.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.34.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/decompress-zip requires graceful-fs@'~3.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.3
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/fstream requires graceful-fs@'~3.0.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.3
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore requires graceful-fs@'~3.0.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.0.3
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore requires mkdirp@'~0.5.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mkdirp,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.3.5
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore requires osenv@'~0.1.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/osenv,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.0.3
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
```

Comment: I don't see any errors. Looking at that, grunt installed successfully.

Comment: if I type in grunt watch it displays the following message Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.

Comment: You've cloned the repository and run `npm install`? Have you even read the [installation manual](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp#quick-start)?

Comment: yes. when I did that it outputted ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies.